# SQL update like fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

```
UPDATE ITEM
SET DaggerAc=0, AxeAc=0, SwordAc=0, MaceAc=0, SpearAc=0, BowAc=0
WHERE strName LIKE "%krowaz%"
```

Error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3  
Invalid column name '%krowaz%'
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: "%krowaz%" => '%krowaz%' ?

Comment: @Mino Post it as an asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"%krowaz%" => '%krowaz%'.
```

In SQL Server you should use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of double quote , use Single quote i.e.

```
UPDATE ITEM
SET DaggerAc=0, AxeAc=0, SwordAc=0, MaceAc=0, SpearAc=0, BowAc=0
WHERE strName LIKE '%krowaz%'
```

Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes generally aren't used in SQL.

Comment: TO add to the answer: In SQL Server double quotes enclose - object names, not strings ;) as the error says (invalid column - the string is interpreted as field name)

Comment: Not entirely correct, this actually depends on QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting.